# How to get the correct wights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

- I'm working on the NLP dataset.
- I Have a data-set which I want to train on classification problem (with 5 classes) and after this phase, I want to use the trained model on the test data in order to build embedding vectors which will be used for the clustering algorithm.

I built the following model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=14000, output_dim=100, input_length=100))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])



Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 100, 100)          1470700   
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 93, 32)            25632     
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d (Global (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                330       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 55        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,496,717
Trainable params: 1,496,717
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

- After fitting the model with train data, I want to predict the test data and get the values (wights) after the flatten layer (I want to use this wights as input to clustering algorithm).

  ```
  for i, val in enumerate(X_test_text):
        y_predict = model.predict(X_test_text[i:i+1])            
        embedding = XXX_get_wights_XXX(i: ??
  ```
- I checked the wights values after predict and the results vector length is different from what I thought:

1. Why  `model.get_layer("flatten").get_weights()` gives me a list of length 0 ? (I was sure that this layer will be used as the embedding layer, and will give me a vector of 32 values)
2. Why `model.get_layer("dense").get_weights()[0].shape` gives tuple (32, 10) ? Why the tuple contains two values and not one ? (just 32 ?)
3. What is the proper way to get a vector of 32 wights (after the flatten layer) for each predicted value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for model output and not model weights. To get model output from your `Flatten` layer you simply have to initialize a new model to extract and produce the output you want...

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=14000, output_dim=100, input_length=100))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.fit(X_train,y_train, ...)
```

Get model output from the `Flatten` layer:

```
n_sample = 20
X_test = np.random.randint(0,14000, (n_sample, 100))

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

intermediate_model = Model(model.inputs, model.get_layer("flatten").output)
intermediate_model.predict(X_test).shape # (n_sample, 32)
```

PS: using `Flatten` after `GlobalMaxPooling` is useless because `GlobalMaxPooling` output is 2D